# Load image dataset from directory in place of MNIST dataset from tf.load

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I want to implement stacked capsule autoencoders (see [here](https://github.com/google-research/google-research/tree/master/stacked_capsule_autoencoders)) on my dataset. While implementing, I am facing the following issues :

The MNIST dataset is loaded as follows:

```
tfds.load(name='mnist', split=subset, **kwargs).repeat().batch(batch_size)
<DatasetV1Adapter shapes: {label: (?,), image: (?, 28, 28, 1)}, types: {label: tf.int64, image: tf.uint8}>
```

I am loading my dataset by replacing the above code as follows:

```
img_list = []
for img in glob.glob("update_207/*.png"):
  n= cv2.imread(img,0)
  img_1 = tf.convert_to_tensor(np.array(n.resize((2000, 1200, 1))))
  img_list.append(img_1) 
tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(img_list).repeat().batch(batch_size)
<DatasetV1Adapter shapes: (?,), types: tf.float32>
```

I am new to Tensorflow so please suggest changes to my code, so that I can get my dataset in a similar shape and type as MNIST.

Answer (score 0):

It would be great to elaborate what you mean with "similar shape and type". In your case it looks like your input images are way larger than the mnist images. This would mean you have to resize them to be 28x28 pixels.

If you let us know what is currently missing we might be able to better help you!

Comment: By shapes and type I mean in this format 
    <DatasetV1Adapter shapes: {label: (?,), image: (?, 28, 28, 1)}, types: {label: tf.int64, image: tf.uint8}> same as MNIST where as I am getting <DatasetV1Adapter shapes: (?,), types: tf.float32> shape & size of image is not an issue at present.

Answer (score 0):

try this one:

```
img_list = []
for img in glob.glob("photos/*.jpg"):
  n= cv2.imread(img)
  img_1 = tf.convert_to_tensor(np.array(cv2.resize(n, (256, 256))))
  img_list.append(img_1) 
train_photos = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(img_list).repeat().batch(64)
```